# Share internet with iPhone over USB

Tags: internet, iphone

I'm shortly going to be working in a place without wifi or mobile data (only wired ethernet connections), and I'd like to be able to use apps on my iPhone (iOS 12.4.1) that require an internet connection. Is it possible to share my laptop's wired internet connection over USB to my phone?

I've seen some comments about doing this from Windows or Mac, and for ubuntu with an Android phone, but not ubuntu to an iphone. Would be interested to know if this is possible for any modern (last five years) release of ubuntu, as I will be working with multiple computers likely on various releases.

Thanks!

(edit: I think the process would be similar to what is described in this [article](https://www.systutorials.com/136003/iphone-connecting-internet-using-windows-pc-network-through-usb-cable/) but I'm not sure how to adapt it to ubuntu)

Comment: Yes you've removed references to Mint, but specifics of releases of Ubuntu would still be useful.  Most releases in the last five years are EOL & thus off-topic, and what is *modern*?  as I deal often with Lubuntu, modern means 18.10 onwards, and one 18.04 flavor is already EOL (having only extended support), so unspecific words are not really helpful.

Comment: I just want to know if it's possible on any of them -- if I choose a specific release and it turns out to be the one that it's not possible on, this is not helpful. Whereas if I knew the one on which it would be possible, I could install it.